# Kubuntu 22.04 with Arabic hints in console

Tags: kubuntu, locale, 22.04

I changed my locale settings to English US in Kubuntu [22.04](/questions/tagged/22.04), but still some system hints in Arabic as shown in the next screenshot of console:

[image]

The installation language was English too. The only thing in Arabic is my timezone location in Cairo/Africa. However, the clock time format is changed to English US, but in the SDDM the time is still in Arabic. How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Check output of `env` in Konsole look for `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`, `LOCALE`, probably one is still on Arabic. How did you change locale, using Kde settings ?